How to count values from a column with JSON content?
I have a table with singers and each singer can be linked to many musical styles.
Musical Styles are in a TEXT column, but the content of the column has JSON format.
I want to count the number of occurences of each musical style.
Here is a sample of my table :



id
Name
elements




1
Elvis Presley
(see code block below)


2
Freddie Mercury
(see code block below)



For example, the column elements includes :
{
    "ffcc1c50-8dbd-4115-b463-b43bdcd44a57": {
        "file": "images\/juke-box\/artistes\/elvis-presley-1.jpg",
        "title": "",
        "width": 250,
        "height": 250
    },

    "2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478": {
        "option": {
            "0": "Gospel",
            "1": "Rock'N Roll"
        },
        "check": "1"
    }

}

or for next row :
{
    "ffcc1c50-8dbd-4115-b463-b43bdcd44a57": {
        "file": "images\/juke-box\/artistes\/freddie-mercury-1.jpg",
        "title": "",
        "width": 250,
        "height": 250
    },

    "2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478": {
        "option": {
            "0": "Gospel",
            "1": "Opera"
        },
        "check": "1"
    }

}

In the example above, Gospel can appear on many artists.
I want to count the number of occurences for each musical style in the whole table.
If I create this query it's very approximative because it's not limited to the "2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478" argument.
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rwm_zoo_item` WHERE `elements` LIKE '%\"Drum And bass\"%') AS "Drum And bass", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rwm_zoo_item` WHERE `elements` LIKE '%\"House\"%') AS "HOUSE", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rwm_zoo_item` WHERE `elements` LIKE '%\"Pop-Rock\"%') AS "Pop Rock", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rwm_zoo_item` WHERE `elements` LIKE '%\"Gospel\"%') AS "Gospel";


As a gentle suggestion for the future, JSON and SQL are not the best of friends.  You might consider whether you would be better served with a product like MongoDB that was designed for JSON.

Please provide your RDBMS version

Oracle:
One option to do it is to define music styles and join them to the data extracted from json using JSON_TABLE().
WITH   -- cte defining styles
  styles (STYLE) AS     
      ( Select 'Gospel' From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Rock''N Roll' From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Opera' From Dual Union All 
        Select 'House' From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Punk' From Dual 
      ),
--  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl (ID, A_NAME, ELEMS) AS
( Select 1, 'Elvis Presley', 
         JSON_SERIALIZE( '{
        "ffcc1c50-8dbd-4115-b463-b43bdcd44a57": {
            "file": "images\/juke-box\/artistes\/elvis-presley-1.jpg",
            "title": "",
            "width": 250,
            "height": 250
        },

        "2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478": {
            "option": {
                "0": "Gospel",
                "1": "Rock''N Roll"
            },
            "check": "1"
        }
    }' RETURNING CLOB)
  From Dual Union All 
  --
  Select 2, 'Freddie Mercury', 
         JSON_SERIALIZE( '{
        "ffcc1c50-8dbd-4115-b463-b43bdcd44a57": {
            "file": "images\/juke-box\/artistes\/freddie-mercury-1.jpg",
            "title": "",
            "width": 250,
            "height": 250
        },

        "2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478": {
            "option": {
                "0": "Gospel",
                "1": "Opera"
            },
            "check": "1"
        }

    }' RETURNING CLOB)
  From Dual
)

--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT      s.STYLE, Count(Case When j.A_NAME Is Not Null Then 1 End) "CNT_STYLE"
FROM        styles s
LEFT JOIN   ( Select   t.ID, t.A_NAME, j.*  
              From     tbl t, 
                       JSON_TABLE( t.ELEMS, '$."2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478".option'
                               COLUMNS ( STYLE_0        VARCHAR2(64)   PATH '$."0"', 
                                         STYLE_1        VARCHAR2(64)   PATH '$."1"', 
                                         STYLE_2        VARCHAR2(64)   PATH '$."2"',
                                         STYLE_3        VARCHAR2(64)   PATH '$."3"', 
                                         STYLE_4        VARCHAR2(64)   PATH '$."4"'
                                       )
                             ) j
            ) j ON( s.STYLE IN( j.STYLE_0, j.STYLE_1, j.STYLE_2, j.STYLE_3, j.STYLE_4 ) )
GROUP BY    s.STYLE
ORDER BY    s.STYLE
/*   R e s u l t :
STYLE        CNT_STYLE
----------- ----------
Gospel               2
House                0
Opera                1
Punk                 0
Rock'N Roll          1   */

MySQL 8.0
Version 8 of MySQL supports JSON_TABLE() function - Cast your data as JSON instead of Oracle JSON_SERIALIZE and change columns datatype to VARCHAR instead of VARCHAR2...
SELECT      s.STYLE, Count(Case When j.A_NAME Is Not Null Then 1 End) "CNT_STYLE"
FROM        styles s
LEFT JOIN   ( Select   t.ID, t.A_NAME, j.*  
              From     tbl t, 
                       JSON_TABLE( t.ELEMS, '$."2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478".option'
                               COLUMNS ( STYLE_0        VARCHAR(64)   PATH '$."0"', 
                                         STYLE_1        VARCHAR(64)   PATH '$."1"', 
                                         STYLE_2        VARCHAR(64)   PATH '$."2"',
                                         STYLE_3        VARCHAR(64)   PATH '$."3"', 
                                         STYLE_4        VARCHAR(64)   PATH '$."4"'
                                       )
                             ) j
            ) j ON( s.STYLE IN( j.STYLE_0, j.STYLE_1, j.STYLE_2, j.STYLE_3, j.STYLE_4 ) )
GROUP BY    s.STYLE
ORDER BY    s.STYLE

/*   R e s u l t :
STYLE        CNT_STYLE
----------- ----------
Gospel               2
House                0
Opera                1
Punk                 0
Rock'N Roll          1   */

MySQL_fiddle v 8.0
MySQL 5.7
... dealing with JSON as a string
SELECT      s.STYLE, Coalesce( Count(a.STYLE), 0 ) as CNT_STYLE
FROM        styles s
LEFT JOIN   ( Select    Case When s.STYLE = SUBSTR(SubStr(t.ELEMS, InStr(t.ELEMS, '"0": "') + 6 ), 1, Length(s.STYLE)) Then s.STYLE Else Null End  as STYLE_0, 
                        Case When s.STYLE = SUBSTR(SubStr(t.ELEMS, InStr(t.ELEMS, '"1": "') + 6 ), 1, Length(s.STYLE)) Then s.STYLE Else Null End  as STYLE_1, 
                        Case When s.STYLE = SUBSTR(SubStr(t.ELEMS, InStr(t.ELEMS, '"2": "') + 6 ), 1, Length(s.STYLE)) Then s.STYLE Else Null End  as STYLE_2, 
                        Case When s.STYLE = SUBSTR(SubStr(t.ELEMS, InStr(t.ELEMS, '"3": "') + 6 ), 1, Length(s.STYLE)) Then s.STYLE Else Null End  as STYLE_3, 
                        Case When s.STYLE = SUBSTR(SubStr(t.ELEMS, InStr(t.ELEMS, '"4": "') + 6 ), 1, Length(s.STYLE)) Then s.STYLE Else Null End  as STYLE_4,
                        s.STYLE as STYLE
              From      styles s
              Left Join ( Select  SubStr( SubStr( ELEMS, InStr(ELEMS, '"2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478":') + 40 ),
                                          InStr(SubStr( ELEMS, InStr(ELEMS, '"2276b834-35d0-4ef0-a747-106ea454e478":') + 40 ), '"option": {') 
                                        ) as ELEMS
                          From     tbl 
                        ) t ON( 1 = 1 )
            ) a  ON(s.STYLE IN(a.STYLE_0, a.STYLE_1 ))
GROUP BY    s.STYLE

/*   R e s u l t :
STYLE        CNT_STYLE
----------- ----------
Gospel               2
House                0
Opera                1
Punk                 0
Rock'N Roll          1   */

MySQL fiddle v 5.7

How do you know OP is using Oracle?

@Charlieface There is no db tag, so I don't know that it's Oracle. The same lack of db tag is also a reason that I don't know it isn't Oracle. That is why I put Oracle at the very start of the answer.

@dr Sorry I forgot to mention it's for MySQL. I just replaced the tag. Do you have any idea on how I can convert this to MySQL ?

@SébastienMerour Just posted MySQL 8 code which is almost identical to Oracle code. If you use older version then you should let us know that. I'm sure it could be done but it will be not as elegant as the two using JSON_TABLE() function.

@SébastienMerour Posted MySQL 5.7 code, too.

@dr Thanks a lot! I understand the 2nd part of the query, but not the 1st part (SELECT      s.STYLE, Count(Case When j.A_NAME Is Not Null Then 1 End) "CNT_STYLE"
FROM        styles s" - What I need to do before this step to use this "style" table. This one doesn't exist.

@SébastienMerour You can see it in the fiddle. There the styles table is declared as a cte. Alternative is to create new table and populate with all music styles that could be in json. Another way is to derive it directly from json either as cte or view...

You'll have to iterate through the objects, and find the "option" values, and aggregate based on the found values.  It might look something like this:
const jukebox = {} // your object
const genreCount = {} // the result

Object.keys(jukebox).forEach((key) => {
  if( !(key.option)) { return; } // no "option" structure here!

  Object.values(key.option).forEach((genre) => {
    if( !genreCount[genre] ) { genreCount[genre] = 0; } // seed initial value
    genreCount[genre] = genreCount[genre]+1;
  });
});

console.log(genreCount);


That's not any dialect of SQL

True, it's a javascript operating on the JSON documents that the OP has in hand.
